# Does Azure Active Directory B2C have a REST Api?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am integrating Azure AD B2C as the authentication server for a product. I cannot tell from the documentation if there is an actual, cURL accessible REST API that I can use to authenticate, create, and manage users. If anyone has experience with Azure AD B2C and knows of a REST API I can use, then I'm golden. Otherwise, I will have to go with another authentication provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Azure AD Graph API to [manage Azure AD B2C account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-user-accounts-graph-api?tabs=applications).

Comment: Just to note that the Graph API can do all the CRUD stuff but it has no authenticate endpoint.